# ansible playbook and hostvar connection

Tags: ansible

I have inventory.ini file that is something like that and no host listed as host values can be updated as per the need.

```
[dev-dbservers]

---
---
[prod-dbservers]
```

to accommodate based on the environment. I want to add accounts differently. In my playbook, how can I use to point to the `dev-dbservers`,  or `prod-dbservers` so it executes as needed per environment

Answer (score 0):

You can use a var in `hosts` parameter in the playbook and you can use `extra-vars` when execute your playbook as below

```yaml
ansible-playbook test.yml -i inventory.ini -e "env=prod-dbservers"
```

and write your playbook as below

```yaml
 ---
 - name: Testing
   hosts: "{{ env }}"
   become: yes
    
   tasks:
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
```